# Next.js v12 middleware does not work with node-fetch and axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, next.js

I am currently trying to create a middleware that will user's data by fetching an external endpoint with Axios. Axios too, does not work with the middleware. Here is my error when using node-fetch:

```
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:buffer" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
```

Any idea why this happens?

Here is my code:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch"
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { NextMiddleware, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const middleware: NextMiddleware = async (req, ev) => {
  const session = await getSession() as any;
  const user = await fetch("some-url", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${session?.user?.someproperty}`,
    },
  });

  if (user.statusCode !== 200) return NextResponse.redirect(req.url);
  else return NextResponse.next();
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using the regular Fetch API (do not import `node-fetch`)? It's supported by Next.js Middleware, see https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/edge-runtime#fetch.

Comment: Nope. I have not, but I will.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was using axios inside middleware, and got the following error

```
error - node_modules\axios\lib\core\dispatchRequest.js (53:0) @ dispatchRequest
TypeError: adapter is not a function
```

I had to install [axios-fetch-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter) according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66305856/typeerror-adapter-is-not-a-function-error-when-using-axios-and-webpack-in-chrom)

My code would like

```js
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import fetchAdapter from '@vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter'
import axios from 'axios'

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
    const axiosInstance = axios.create({
        adapter: fetchAdapter
    })

    const data = await axiosInstance.get('/whatever-url')

    // the rest of the code

}
```

Or if you already had a preconfigured instance with custom options

```js
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import fetchAdapter from '@vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter'
import axiosInstance from './the-path-of-your-instance'

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
    axiosInstance.defaults.adapter = fetchAdapter

    const data = await axiosInstance.get('/whatever-url')

    // the rest of the code

}
```

Comment: It's returning is for me: `error - (middleware)\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js (16:0) @ createError`

Comment: @BrunoYuzo Can you provide your code, or a pen? So we can try to help you better

Comment: Getting a different error: 
`error - ./node_modules/@vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter/index.js:2:0
Module not found: Package path ./lib/core/settle is not exported from package /.../node_modules/axios (see exports field in /.../node_modules/axios/package.json)`

Comment: I'm getting the same error as @PatrickYan