# Error when using Axios-based package in a Chrome extension background script

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, axios, xmlhttprequest, vite

I'm currently developing a Chrome extension using React, and I've encountered an issue in the background script of my extension. The problem arises from my use of a package that internally relies on Axios to make HTTP requests. However, Chrome extensions seem to use the XMLHttpRequest object for HTTP requests, which leads to the following error:

```
Error: adapter is not a function
```

Tried this thread

[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66305856/typeerror-adapter-is-not-a-function-error-when-using-axios-and-webpack-in-chrom)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.